# bootstrap: Slider on 2 spans ? - one span=image, one span=textblock

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I have some segments that are similar on my page, same setup - one icon-logo and one text-area:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span7"> 
  <img src="img/icon2.png" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div class="span4">
  <h6>My Text Area</h6>
   <p>Description of that functionality<br>
   Multi lines of text<p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Just basically an icon and a description text, started out with having 2 of these which is alright, now there is 8 and i think i would like to gather it in one segment, but then slide between the 8 icons/descriptions.

So my question is, any chance or any component available where i can put in 8 of these in a slider-effect way ? most sliders I've looked at is image sliders, but since i need to have multi-language i don't want to convert the 2 spans into 1 image.

I am not an expert in web development so an example would really be appreciated if its possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bootstrap carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel) for this.

This is the markup they expect

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">[here]</div>
    <div class="item">[here]</div>
    <div class="item">[here]</div>
</div>
```

All you need to do is to have your two `spans` inside the element with class `item`.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/MgcDU/6649/). Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Not appropiate to post just to say thanks i know that, but hope you recognize the "answered" is a big thank-you :)